# How to avoid so many disconnects in IoT-edge module

Tags: c#, azure-iot-edge

Having implemented a nice working iotEdge-module following the newest code-template (from VSCode), I have now implemented a method

```
private static void ConnectionStatusChangeHandler(ConnectionStatus status, ConnectionStatusChangeReason reason)
        {
            reports++;
            if ((reports % 20)==0) {
                Console.WriteLine("[{2}] Connection Status Changed to {0} ({1}) (now {3} reports).", status, reason, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("u"), reports);
            }
}
```

This method is called approximately 1 million times per hour, which seems wrong. For that hour, the connection has been stable. I would like to have the option of changing state of the module in case it goes offline.

As you can see, I am not printing output for test purposes on every call as that would crash the device.

I am expecting a stable connection with the IoT-Hub and not that many disconnects. I seem to do something wrong, but I cannot figure out where.

Init-code:

```
static async Task Init()
    {
        MqttTransportSettings mqttSetting = new MqttTransportSettings(TransportType.Mqtt_Tcp_Only);
        ITransportSettings[] settings = { mqttSetting };
        device_id = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IOTEDGE_DEVICEID");
        s_deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ioTConnString + ";DeviceId=" + device_id.ToString() + ";", TransportType.Mqtt);
        s_deviceClient.SetConnectionStatusChangesHandler(ConnectionStatusChangeHandler);
    }
```

Comment: I assume your module is using the C# SDK (Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client). What version are you using?

Comment: I am using the same status handler in my modules and they really only get called when something really changed in the connection. So there must be an issue with your module->EdgeHub connection. Can you please post the code you use inside your module to create the connection?

Comment: Yes indeed, I am running Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client  1.21.0 - which I assume is the newest.

Comment: Added Init code to OP , and I am thinking that the problem here is that I am creating a device-client and not only a module-client, I have had that problem before.

Comment: why are you creating a DeviceClient instead of a module client?

Answer (score 0):

How about only logging when the connection status changes?

Assuming `ConnectionStatus` is an enum, this code might do the trick.
I made `_previousStatus` nullable so that the logging will definitely fire the first time the method is called.

```cs
        ConnectionStatus? _previousStatus;
        private static void ConnectionStatusChangeHandler(ConnectionStatus status, ConnectionStatusChangeReason reason) {
            if (status != _previousStatus) {
                _previousStatus = status;
                Console.WriteLine("[{2}] Connection Status Changed to {0} ({1}) (now {3} reports).", status, reason, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("u"), reports);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you thought about concurrency? Is this method called by competing threads?